# Git clone error in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, git

Up until now I've been using Xcode with Subversion for my code repositories with no problem. Now I'm working on a project that uses a Git repository stored at GitHub, so I figured I'd go clone that repository to my local machine and get started.

In Xcode, I add the repository then tell it to Clone -- The machine chews on this for a while, and if I use the Finder I can see the files being placed in the target directory (which is a newly-created, empty directory on my system).  After a while though, I get an error message:

fatal: destination path '/Users/myname/Documents/ProjectName' already exists and is not an empty directory.

I have tried this three times now, each time starting with an empty target directory, and it gives the same error message each time, so I know it has to be something I am doing wrong, or have not set up properly.

Thinking that perhaps something was going wrong and the system was trying to do a second clone operation (to a now non-empty directory) I tried canceling and trying a build, but some files are missing from the project -- so not all of it made it down to my system.

My searches on this issue turn up several hits for people doing the clone via command line and showing this error message, but not through the Xcode interface.

Does anyone have any suggestions about what might be going wrong?

Comment: Did you try to clone this repo using the terminal? Just to isolate the cause of the error and be sure that the problem is not due to XCode.